# Unity sound not working after AVAudioSession is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, avaudiosession

I'm currently working on a Unity3D iOS plugin. I'm trying to change the category of the app's AVAudioSession in order to implement audio ducking (i.e. Music app volume goes down while my sound effects are playing), which requires the AVAudioSession to be set as inactive and then as active again.

Well, after I set the session as inactive by using `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil]`, Unity sounds simply won't work anymore, even after the session is set as active again. Native sounds still work, as I tested an AVAudioPlayer and it works perfectly.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [daniel_liu](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/603021/daniel-liu-1.html) from Unity Answers [helped me with this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/995956/unity-sounds-not-playing-after-avaudiosession-is-d.html#answer-1021921): Instead of setting the AVAudioSession as active/inactive by using the code I posted in the question, one should use `UnitySetAudioSessionActive(true)` and `UnitySetAudioSessionActive(false)`.